# I hope you can see what I'm getting at: Questions Tags / Users Bags / answer Question / UnAsk What lags?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> Questions Tags
>
> Users Bags
>
> answer Question
>
> UnAsk What lags?

**Instructions**

Explain what lags.

You must use *all* the clues and explain precisely how you got the answer from them.

Please do not guess random phrases that might fit. You must explain the clues.

The answer is two words.

_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ /_ _ _ _  (8, 4)

> Use upper and lower case appropriately when you answer.

Comment: I thought this could be a smart puzzle, but your choice of answer has left me disappointed.

Comment: It could have been. My problem is that I get too enthusiastic and rush into things. I am always convinced that I have set it up right. I think there is a life lesson in this for me. Well, I expect to get a record number of downvotes for this. I think I'll take a break, make up some puzzles, let them simmer and come back when I am certain they work.

Comment: When I saw 'd e ed' were the missing letters, I thought the second word would be deed, the first being something else, with some reference cleverly disguised. But the fact that you left out letters was not even relevant. It just seems like we had to recognize those words, use the (8,4) as a clue and post the first thing that came to our minds.

Comment: Note - I have accepted Stefano's answer because it is the nearest you can get given the flaw in my clues. The 'correct' answer would  have been *deed*. @CodeNewbie - I agree with you. The question could have been much better if I had taken time to formulate it better.

Comment: So the intent was to be "Q: what lags? A: deed"?  I don't understand.

Comment: What lags? = What is left behind? or What lingers?  When you subtract my clues from the original, the thing that is left behind is the letters d e e d.  Definition:- "to lag" ---> https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=lag+definition&ie=&oe=

Comment: http://sd.keepcalm-o-matic.co.uk/i/keep-calm-and-put-it-down-to-experience.png

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is:

> Puzzling

Explanation:

> The hyperlinks on the right of Puzzling page are lagged to create the 4 clues

Comment: that leaves exactly 4 letters remaining which spell out deed. Could this just be the start of the puzzle?

Comment: Now I've noticed. Maybe my solution is wrong; remaining letters could be part of the solution...

Comment: @chaslyfromUK d and e are left over from Badges, ed is left over from Unanswered.

Comment: Aarghh! I had made a resolution not to rush into setting a question. My original answer was in fact 'deed' and then I got too clever and forgot what I was doing  :-( Please feel free to downvote me. Maybe I'll learn from this.

Comment: I have accepted this because it is the best you can do with my flawed clues.

Answer (score 5):

Stefano has correctly deduced that

> the links at the top of the site (to the right of "Puzzling")

are used to create the apparently meaningless string of words "Questions Tags / Users Bags / answer Question / UnAsk", with also the extra letters **d e ed**. So what we're left over with is the word "deed"; however this isn't in the (8,4) form required for the solution.

So let's search Puzzling SE for the word "deed". We get [this list of results](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=deed), of which the top hit is [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/617/kruskals-hard-to-refold-envelope). You'll notice that it was posted by one **shamisen** (8 letters) and the most recent edit was by **JLee** (4 letters). So the final (8,4) answer is:

> shamisen JLee

... and indeed the capitalisation is hard to get right!

Comment: Haha! Very good.